# Angular2 How to use ngIf to show some other text if there's empty value in json Object?

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

Hi I'm having trouble understanding ngIf.

Currently I have json object of

```
Profile:{
0:{name: 'Jen',
intro:'',
gender:'female',
age:'1992'},
1:{name: 'John',
intro:'Hi',
gender:'male',
age:'1988'}
}
```

The first object's intro is empty string and when it has empty string I want to display 'The user hasn't written it yet'.

I tried using ngIf like this but of course this doesn't work. What should I do?

```
<div *ngFor="let p of Profile">
                <p class="fontstyle2">
                    {{p.intro}}
                </p>

                <p class="fontstyle2" *ngIf="p.intro=''">
                    The user hasn't written it yet
                </p>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

it should be == not =

```
 <p class="fontstyle2" *ngIf="p.intro==''">
   The user hasn't written it yet
 </p>
```

Answer (score 3):

`ngIf` uses javascript syntax for comparisons so you can use `p.intro === ''` or just `!p.intro` since an empty string is falsy.

Another thing is that you'd probably want to display only one of the alternatives so you should use `ngIf` in both:

```
<div *ngFor="let p of Profile">
    <p class="fontstyle2" *ngIf="p.intro">
                {{p.intro}}
    </p>

    <p class="fontstyle2" *ngIf="!p.intro">
        The user hasn't written it yet
    </p>
</div>
```

Another option would be to do it in this way:

```
<div *ngFor="let p of Profile">
    <p class="fontstyle2">
         {{p.intro? p.intro : "The user hasn't written it yet"}}
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to display **The user hasn't written it yet**  when  **intro** is blank and if its not blank then you want to display value of **Intro**

For this you can use following code snippet :

```
        <div *ngFor="let p of Profile">
            <p class="fontstyle2" *ngIf="p.intro!=''">
                {{p.intro}}
            </p>

            <p class="fontstyle2" *ngIf="p.intro===''">
                The user hasn't written it yet
            </p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As many of here said you need to use `===` instead of just `=` over with the condition.

```
<div *ngFor="let p of Profile">
    <p class="fontstyle2">
        {{p.intro}}
    </p>
    <p class="fontstyle2" *ngIf="p.intro===''">
        The user hasn't written it yet
    </p>
</div>
```

or you can simply check for `!`

```
<div *ngFor="let p of Profile">
    <p class="fontstyle2">
        {{p.intro}}
    </p>
    <p class="fontstyle2" *ngIf="!p.intro">
        The user hasn't written it yet
    </p>
</div>
```